# How to integrate auto-renewable subscription of In-App purchase IOS 8

Tags: ios8, in-app-purchase, xcode6, itunes

I am developing an app using IOS 8 in which i am using In-App purchase with auto renewable. here i am getting an issue while testing on sandbox that it always ask for subscription when i am trying to buy using same user.
if i follow same procedure for Non-Consumable type of In-App purchase, it's working fine and giving proper message as "you are already purchased".I am new in app development.Kindly help me to resolve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you implement the code for this? If yes, then please help..

Comment: Yes i have executed,  Don't worry that was sandbox issue, when your app published with auto renewable, then  it work properly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now my question is how did you check for restore purchase or if user cancels the auto renewable subscription in app? Can you please provide some code if possible?